# Does this count as a valid bubble sorting function? If so, how could I improve it?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm a complete novice to sorting algorithms so right now I'm more or less just trying to pick up the basics. This is something I wrote in C++ to sort a string and return it's characters in alphabetical order. I'm fairly confident this counts as a bubble sort, but I'd like confirmation from the experts :). I'd also like to get your take on how it could be further improved?

```
bool inOrder(std::string s){
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        int thisLetterNum = s[i];
        int nextLetterNum = s[i + 1];
        if(thisLetterNum > nextLetterNum){
            return false;
        }
    }
return true;
}
std::string alphabetSoup(std::string str) {
    std::string &result = str;
    while(!inOrder(result)){
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            int thisLetterNum = str[i];
            int nextLetterNum = str[i + 1];
            if(thisLetterNum > nextLetterNum){
                result[i] = nextLetterNum;
                result[i + 1] = thisLetterNum;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *I'd also like to get your take on how it could be further improved?* -- Improving a bubble sort is like trying to improve a mud sandwich.  Use a different sort altogether, as bubble sort is one of the worst ones to use.

Comment: BTW, this line: `int nextLetterNum = s[i + 1];` is an out-of-bounds access on the last iteration of that `for` loop.

Comment: Paul beat me to it. You won't find many bubble sort experts for the same reason. No one uses it outside of introductory computer programming courses. If you've taken enough of those to qualify as an expert... Well... Ouch.

Comment: I think Donald Knuth (or one of those vaunted CS guys) stated that it shouldn't even taught in schools.

Comment: If it works ask for a code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Deleted my answer. Of course this should be on code review instead.

Comment: @user4581301 I disagree with that. Bubble sort has a very low cost overhead and has a best case complexity of O(n). Thus it is excellent for cases where `n` is small. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case The "Better" algorithms usually have much higher overhead and best case of `O(n.log(n))`.

Comment: Not going to argue with that. In fact, hoisted with my own petard. Argued the same thing yesterday with `vector` vs `map` look-ups in a small table.

Comment: @TedLyngmo your answer still has merit. It picked off a legit bug in the program that should be addressed before code review.

Comment: @user4581301 That's true I guess. I'll undelete it :)

Comment: BTW, it was [Owen Astrachan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen_Astrachan) that recommended that the bubble sort not be taught to introductory CS students, as it is of little value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a form of bubble sorting.

> I'd also like to get your take on how it could be further improved

You have undefined behavior when `i = length() - 1` because you use `str[i + 1]` so fixing that is the first improvement I would suggest.

You could also make fewer iterations and skip `inOrder()`. You can keep track of if it's in order by noting if you made a swap or not instead.

Example:

```
std::string alphabetSoup(std::string str) {
    bool swapped;
    size_t ei = str.length();
    do {
        --ei; // you can decrease this each iteration since the last element will be in
              // the correct place after each iteration
        swapped = false;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < ei; ++i) {
            if(str[i + 1] < str[i]) {
                std::swap(str[i], str[i + 1]);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while(swapped);

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A third improvement. Decrement
`str.length()`
by 1 each pass. This changes the behavior from n^2 to quadratic  ((n * n) + n) / 2. This, coupled with the previous suggestions, radically improves exchange sort [another name for bubble sort]. Unfortunately, it is still inferior to other sort methods, just way easy to code.

Comment: That's actually one of the two suggestions I made in my answer :-)